# Sidebar endpoint using WordPress API

Tags: rest-api, sidebar

I cannot find any info on this. Is there a default endpoint for sidebars?

For example pages:

```
http://localhost:8888/example/wp-json/wp/v2/pages
```

I have looked at the WordPress API documentation but don't see any endpoints for sidebars or widgets.

I also tried something basic like this:

```
function sidebar_api( $data ) {
    
    $response_body = get_sidebar('one');
    return new WP_REST_Response(
        array(
            'body_response' => $response_body
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'custom/v1', 'sidebar1', array(
        'methods'  => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'sidebar_api',
    ) );
} );
```

which gives me the sidebar not in json format and then a json response with an empty body_response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a default endpoint for sidebars?

No, I don't think there is. So (for now), using a custom REST API endpoint does sound like a good option to me.

> gives me the sidebar not in json format and then a json response with an empty `body_response`

That's because `get_sidebar()` echo the output, hence the `$response_body` is empty.

So you'd want to use output buffering like so:

```php
ob_start();
get_sidebar( 'one' );
$response_body = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: Ahhh, thank you!